# Utilise-t-on „fut“ plus souvent que d‘autres verbes au passe simple?

Tags: grammaire, usage

Je sais qu‘on utilise le passé simple normalement seulement dans des romans. Mais j‘ai plusieurs fois entendu dire/vu le verbe fut, qui est apparu de n‘importe où.

1. à la radio France Inter ou France Culture. Le présentateur a raconté un événement du 20 siècle et il a dit „il fut un temps où....
2. Quelqu‘un a expliqué ses recherches anatomique et écrit après „Le résultat fut une pratique de deux heures“

Pourquoi utilise-t-on „être“ au passé simple mais voit rarement d‘autres verbes au passé simple dans des textes quotidien (publicités, post instagram...) ou à la radio, à la télé

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*Il fut un temps* est une formulation relativement courante pour introduire une affirmation qui était vraie il y a relativement longtemps. D'autres expressions équivalentes sont *à une certaine époque*, *il y a bien longtemps*.
En effet, l'utilisation du passé simple à l'oral a quasiment (pour ne pas dire totalement) disparu, *il fut un temps* est une formulation figée et fait figure d'exception.

Dans le 2e cas, tu précises que c'est à l'écrit donc c'est moins inhabituel.
Même à l'oral, cela pourrait être attendu dans certains cas, par exemple une présentation desdites recherches lors d'une thèse, une conférence, etc. L'orateur peut avoir préparé son texte à l'avance, ou tout simplement choisir un registre plus soutenu que lors d'une conversation.

Answer (score 2):

Le passé simple est un temps du récit, et non seulement du roman.

À propos du passé simple, sur la page [wikipedia](https://fr.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pass%C3%A9_simple_en_fran%C3%A7ais) :

> Selon Émile Benveniste, le passé simple est non déictique, tout comme le récit qui est son cadre d'emploi quasi exclusif, ce qui s'accompagne d'une impression de distanciation ou d'éloignement temporel avec l'événement mentionné. Au contraire, le discours et ses temps (passé composé, par exemple) sont déictiques, c'est-à-dire ancrés dans la situation d'énonciation. Ainsi, l'auxiliaire au présent du passé composé constitue l'ancre dans le présent des interlocuteurs.

Les deux exemples donnés sont très différents et exigent une explication pour chaque :

1. L’expression “il fut un temps” sert précisément à exprimer cet éloignement, le passé simple est donc bien à sa place. En dehors de cette expression, on cherche généralement au contraire un rapprochement de l’action dans les conversations de tous les jours.
2. Pour le deuxième exemple, il s’agit d’un contexte académique où la distance vis à vis du récit est recherchée et permet d’afficher une forme de rigueur scientifique. L’usage du passé simple ne s’y borne pas seulement au verbe être mais les textes scientifiques sont le plus souvent descriptifs et il est normal d’y avoir une prépondérance de cet auxiliaire.

Comment: C’est vrai que c’est pas évident sans contexte mais en fait j‘ai vu le deuxième exemple sur Instagram. Il s‘agit des recherches personnelles qui ont conduit à un pratique de Yoga de 2 heures...